# insert Placeholder into primefaces Text Editor body

Tags: primefaces, quill

I am using primefaces texteditor to create email templates which the user can later use to send an email to a candidate.

in these models I would like to insert a placeholder that will be replaced at the time of sending by the appropriate value.
in the body of the texteditor I would like it to appear as a non-editable tag like in the image below :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxRpA.jpg)

Is there a way to make that possibile with textEditor ?